# Auto Language Translation Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, translation

I am working on Drupal 7 and I am stuck with language translation.

I have a Social Networking Site on which I allow user to post data. I allow user to post their data in three languages. User has the option of choosing any one of the three languages and post data.

Now my requirement is that if an English User posts data/message in English, then another Chinese User must be able to see that message in Chinese. So the requirement is that no matter whichever language a data is posted in, it must be visible to all the users in their own language.

Can Drupal provide this automated feature? If yes , then how. I have been trying multiple things but have'nt succeeded to get what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this post and Molot's answer about this topic: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135227/auto-translate-content-of-nodes

> **It will never be good**. Human languages are not something perfectly unambiguous and logical, so no computer software will ever be able to translate them perfectly. **You need a human to properly translate human languages.**